# Usefulness of an iron core in a magnetic coil used to generate current

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I wish to light a LED by moving a permanent magnet relative to an inductor consisting of a coil of copper wire. Can I increase efficiency (current produced for a given magnet motion) by using an iron or ferrite core in my magnetic coil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, that is what is regularly done in all common AC generators - the coils are wound on special steel poles with high permeability. Well placed ferromagnetic core can increase the induced emf in wires by three and even more orders of magnitude.